# Core Data: Z_ENT Column has incorrect value

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an issue where a record in the database is not being retrieved by the `NSFetchedResultsController`. After investigations, I found that the record has wrong z_ent value. It should be 8, while it has the value 9. My question is what could possibly cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the data model had a parent and child entities. Core Data save both records in the same table in the database but with different entity ID.